# Easiest to use IDE and dependency manager for importing C++ libraries on windows

Tags: windows, c++, dependencies

I want to use some of the great c++ libraries out there (e.g. cgal), but don't know how (have been exclusively writing my own code so far). It seems every library requires a different process in order to use it (at least on windows)

I'm currently using Clion as an IDE in Windows 10 with minGW. I've tried using the Conan dependency manager but couldn't get it to work (and the documentation/video tutorials are not done very well).

Is there a recommended simple way to do it?

Is using vcpkg dependency manager with the visual studio IDE a good way to go about it?

For clarification, I am an academic physicist developing scientific simulations mostly to be used by myself, so I don't have to package my code with all the dependencies included. I will only need to run the thing in two configurations. On my laptop and later on a university cluster.

Thanks.